# объясните оптимизацию с -O2

Tags: ассемблер

для шарящих людей, думаю, вопрос элементарный, но я не могу врубиться... вот есть функция

```
unsigned int
hash(const unsigned char *data, const size_t data_len) {
  unsigned int hash = 0x4841434B;
  for(int i = 0; i < data_len; i++) {
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + data[i];
  }
  return hash;
}
```

при -O0 понятно что генерируется:

```
hash(unsigned char const*, unsigned long):
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $1212236619, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
.L7:
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    cmpq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    jnb     .L6
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    sall    $5, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    leal    (%rdx,%rax), %ecx
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    movslq  %eax, %rdx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    movzbl  (%rax), %eax
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    addl    %ecx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
    jmp     .L7
.L6:
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

все начинается с засовывания в стек аргументов функций и пошло поехало...
но вот не понятно с -O2:

```
hash(unsigned char const*, unsigned long):
    testq   %rsi, %rsi
    je      .L6
    addq    %rdi, %rsi
    movl    $1212236619, %eax
.L5:
    movzbl  (%rdi), %ecx
    movl    %eax, %edx
    addq    $1, %rdi
    sall    $5, %edx
    addl    %ecx, %edx
    addl    %edx, %eax
    cmpq    %rdi, %rsi
    jne     .L5
    rep ret
.L6:
    movl    $1212236619, %eax
    ret
```

1. зачем регистр rsi проверяется на нуль?
2. почему вообще именно rsi?
3. почему нету ничего связанного со стеком, должен же хотя бы адрес возврата в стек заноситься...

Comment: Компилятор использовал соглашение о вызовах, которое ему больше понравилось. Если указать явно __attribute__((cdecl)) или __attribute__((stdcall)), то он перестанет так делать.

Comment: да честно говоря ни cdecl ни stdcall не меняют ничего...

Comment: Да, точно. Под amd64 это не работает.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1, 2 - В данном случае параметры передаются не через стек, а через `rsi` и `rdi`. Поэтому и проверка на 0 идет у одного из этих регистров.

3 - Адрес возврата в стек заносится автоматически при вызове функции через `call`, специально его туда заносить не нужно. Если в функции нет стековых переменных, то и со стеком ничего связанного не будет.

**Уточнение.**

Адрес возврата сохраняется автоматически при вызове процедуры через `call`. Сам по себе `call` эквивалентен двум командам: `push` и `jmp` (на стек кладется адрес возврата, потом уже выполняется переход в указанное место). `ret` наоборот - берет адрес возврата со стека (эквивалентно `pop`), и делает переход на него (`jmp`).

Конструкция вида

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp

...

popq    %rbp
; и дальше ret
```

не имеет никакого отношения к адресу возврата. На самом деле - это стандартный пролог/эпилог для создания [стекового кадра](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80), внутри которого создаются стековые переменные. Если стековые переменные в процедуре не используются (например, если компилятору удалось обойтись только регистрами), то и стековый кадр не нужен, соответственно и пролог с эпилогом могут отсутствовать.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что так как оптимизатор решает избавится от переменной i предварительным вычислением адреса конца строки и сравнения непосредственно адресов, то ему становится удобнее проверка условия цикла в конце, а не в начале. И т.к. условие теперь проверяется слишком поздно, то проверку на 0 (цикл вообще не выполняется) надо проводить заранее, отсюда и проверка длины на 0

Comment: @insolor, 3) ну вот, допустим, запустил я с -O0... идет call и далее прыгаем в функцию в которой уже там push и т.д. то тут понятно... другое дело, что с -O2 у меня функцию заинлайнилась, то да, не нужно ничего со стеком воротить... но если бы не заинлайнилась, то ведь все равно бы push и т.д. не было бы... почему?

Comment: @xperious, ничего не заинлайнилось -- `ret` в конце видите? А зачем тут push? Что именно и зачем вы собрались сохранять?  В System V AMD64 ABI принято -- `If the callee wishes to use registers RBP, RBX, and R12–R15, it must restore their original values before returning control to the caller. All others must be saved by the caller if it wishes to preserve their values.` / Кстати, если `movl    $1212236619, %eax` переместить в самое начало, то пару команд можно выбросить

Comment: @avp, не, если засобачить в main, то она инлайнилась... другое дело что добавил в функцию всякой ерунды чтобы не могла заинлайнится - вуаля, в начале функции появилась заветная pushq   %rbx... теперь разобрался

Comment: @xperious, обратите внимание как в main с -O3 она интересно инлайнится. Если написать `printf("%u\n", hash(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));`, то в инлайн коде в качестве второго аргумента используется `rax` (результат strlen), а результат вычисляется сразу в `edx` (второй параметр для printf) / Кстати, код самой `hash` (вместе с `.globl hash` и  `ret` в конце) тоже присутствует, но он из main не вызывается.

Comment: @xperious, ближе к вечеру дополню ответ по поводу "заветных pushq"

Comment: @insolor, было б замечательно)

Comment: @xperious, собственно, вчера уже все написал, что планировал.